# which sentence is correct

Tags: sentence

1- The choice of the setting comes as a result of the researcher being a permeant teacher at the school.

2-   The choice of the setting comes as a result of the researcher who is a permeant teacher at the school.

The idea is like sentence one : the teacher works at that school so the research setting choice .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First sentence is correct

*The choice of the setting comes as a result of the researcher being a permeant teacher at the school.*

X is a result of... the researcher being Y

X is not a result of the researcher himself, X is a result of the situation (him being a permanent teacher there)

Answer (score -2):

Sentence 1 is correct, but it should be better with this change-

> The choice of the setting comes as a result of the **researcher's** being a permeant teacher at the school.

Comment: it is not a result of the researcher himself, I explained in my answer

Comment: Then it should be like- The choice of the setting comes as a result of the researcher's being a permeant teacher at the school.